# Java custom to string returning Memory location

Tags: java, tostring

My original toString method in my CirculaList class works fine. However when I call it in my toString method in my stack class it returns what I assume is the memory location of my stack. I've tried overloading it but to no distinguishable diferrence.

My code:

**CircularList class**

```
public class CircularList{
private Node tail = null;
public void addToFront(int elem){
    if(elem >= 0){
        Node newNode= new Node(elem);
        if(tail != null){
            newNode.next = tail.next;
            tail.next = newNode;
        }else{
            tail = newNode;
            newNode.next = newNode;
        }   
    }
}

public int deleteFromBack(){
    int returned = -1;
    if(tail != null){
        Node trav = tail;
        while(trav.next != tail){
            trav = trav.next;
        }
        returned = tail.data;
        if(trav.next == trav){
            tail = null;
        }else{
            trav.next = tail.next;
            tail = trav;
        }
    }
    return returned;
}
//@Override
public String toSting(){
    String stg = null;
    stg = "[";
    Node trav = tail.next;
    while(trav != tail){
        stg += trav.getData() +",";
        trav = trav.next;
    }
    stg += trav.getData() + "]";
    return stg;
}

public CircularList clone(CircularList other){
    tail = other.tail;
    return this;
}

}
```

**Stack Class**

```
public class Stack{
private CircularList list = new CircularList();

public void push(int elem){
    list.addToFront(elem);
}

public int pop(){
    CircularList tempList = new CircularList();
    int keeper = -1;
    if(isEmpty() != true){
        keeper =list.deleteFromBack();
        while(isEmpty() != true){
            tempList.addToFront(keeper);
            keeper =list.deleteFromBack();
        }
        list.clone(tempList);
    }
    return keeper;
}

public int peek(){
    CircularList tempList = new CircularList();
    int keeper = -1;
    if(isEmpty() != true){
        while(!isEmpty()){
            keeper = list.deleteFromBack();
            tempList.addToFront(keeper);
        }
        list.clone(tempList);
    }
    return keeper;
}



public boolean isEmpty(){
    CircularList tempList = new CircularList();
    int keeper = -1;
    keeper = list.deleteFromBack();
    if(keeper==-1){
        return true;
    }else{
        while(keeper!=-1){
            tempList.addToFront(keeper);
            keeper = list.deleteFromBack();
        }
        list.clone(tempList);
    }
    return false;
}

public Stack clone(Stack other){
    list = other.list;
    return this;
}
//@Override
public String toSting(){
    String stg = list.toString();
    return stg;
}

}
```

**Tester class** (As the name suggest it is purely for testing)

```
public class Tester{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    CircularList list = new CircularList();

    System.out.println("CircularList");
    System.out.println("=========");
    list.addToFront(1);
    list.addToFront(2);
    list.addToFront(3);
    list.addToFront(4);
    list.addToFront(5);
    System.out.println(list.toSting());
    System.out.println("=========");

    System.out.println("removing: " + list.deleteFromBack());
    System.out.println("=========");

    System.out.println(list.toSting());
    System.out.println("=====================================================");

    System.out.println("stack");
    System.out.println("=========");
    Stack stack = new Stack();

    System.out.println(stack.isEmpty());

    System.out.println("=========");

    stack.push(1);
    stack.push(2);
    stack.push(3);
    stack.push(4);
    stack.push(5);
    System.out.println(stack.toString());
    System.out.println(stack.isEmpty());
    System.out.println("=========");
    System.out.println("first int: " + stack.peek());
    System.out.println("=========");
    System.out.println("Removing: " + stack.pop());
    System.out.println(stack.isEmpty());
}
}
```

**Output** (equals taken out as they were messing with the layout)
CircularList

[5,4,3,2,1]

removing: 1

[5,4,3,2]

stack

true

Stack@15db9742
false

first int: 5

Removing: 5
false

Comment: `toSting` is not `toString`

Comment: I ask 3 other people for help with this. Not any one of us could find this. Thanks.

Comment: Maybe that is also the reason why you commented the `@Override` line ;) Because there was an error while compiling?

Comment: It's not a memory location. Its a randomly generated hashCode.

Answer (score 0):

toSting() has been used instead of toString(), hence Object class toString() is called.
@Override can be useful in such cases which is trying to tell us that we have done some mistake while overriding the method.
It can always be helpful to think before commenting @Override.